# Armazenar diversas informações em um bloco de notas com batch

Tags: cmd, batch

Bom dia, primeiramente vou contextualizar. Basicamente eu estou fazendo uma "história interativa", onde basicamente, durante o progresso da história eu vou ter 3 variaveis. Eu poderia salvar essas variaveis com o comando set dentro da programação e funcionaria, mas eu gostaria de uma forma de salvar essas variaveis externamente (em um bloco de notas), por que assim o "progresso" não é perdido. Então minha dúvida é: como eu salvo variaveis de um coma do batch em um bloco de notas que o mesmo cria? E como eu faço para que o arquivo batch saiba ler e separar as informações colocadas nesse bloco de notas criados?

Por exemplo, eu dei set em "%A%" como 2, "%B%" como 5 e "%C%" como 1. No bloco de notas ele salva "2 5 1" e assim que eu uso o batch novamente, ele da set em A B C nesses mesmos valores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - Update: item **1)** ***Salvando*** no Próprio Bat

---

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & title <nul & title Q344161

for /f "skip=8tokens=1,2,3delims=-" %%a in ('type "%~f0"')do if "%%a-"=="-" (
   goto :_salve_variaveis ) else echo/A = %%a B = %%b C = %%c & goto :eof

:_salve_variaveis
set /a A=1 + 1, B=4 + 1, C=0 + 1 & cmd /v /c echo/!A!-!B!-!C!->>"%~f0" & exit /b
rem :: As suas variaveies sarao salvas abaixo:
```

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

- As opções que conheço e já usei/testei:

  **1)** No Próprio Bat

  **2)** No Arquivo abc.txt

  **3)** No Registro do Window

---

**1) :: Usando o proprio bat para salvar/recuperar variáveis nele mesmo!! ::**

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "skip=12 tokens=1,2,3 delims=-" %%a in ('type "%~f0"') do ( 
     if "%%a-" == "-" goto :_salve_variaveis
     echo/A = %%a B = %%b C = %%c && goto :eof
    )
:_salve_variaveis
set /a A=1 + 1
set /a B=4 + 1
set /a C=0 + 1
echo/!A!-!B!-!C!->>"%~f0"
call "%~f0" && exit /b
rem | As suas variáveis serão salvas na linha abaixo:
```

**2) :: Usando apenas o bloco de notas (abc.txt) para salvar e recuperar valores A, B e C ::**

```bat
@echo off

set A=2
set B=5
set C=1

echo/%A%-%B%-%C%>.\abc.txt
```

**:: Lendo o bloco de notas (abc.txt) e recuperando os valores de A,B e C ::**

```bat
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=-" %%a in ('type .\abc.txt') do (

    set A=%%a
    set B=%%b
    set C=%%c
    echo/%A% %B% %C%
)
```

**3) :: Usando o Registro do Windows via setx e/ou reg add/reg query/ reg delete** ::

```bat
    ::  Escreva suas variáveis concatenando os valores numa chave do registro do windows
    ::  Usando o comando setx ou reg add, de maneira que não seja necessário chamar outro
    ::  Arquivo, nem saber o caminho dele. O setx registra variáveis para uso "global", 
    ::  porém só efetivamente disponibiliza a variável na próxima vez que chamar o cmd, daí entra.
    ::  o artifício de ler os valores não numa variável, mas sim numa entrada  
    ::  de registro via reg query e apagando quando não mais for necessário.

        @echo off

        set A=2
        set B=5
        set C=1

        :: Para escrever via setx: 
        setx a-b-c %A%-%B%-%C%

        :: Ou ecreva direto no registro sem usar o setx via reg add:
        set a-b-c=%A%-%B%-%C%&
        reg add HKCU\Environment /v a-b-c /d "%A%-%B%-%C%" /f 

        :: Para ler o registro em outro tempo e recuperar os valores de %A%-%B%-%C%:
        for /f "tokens=3 delims=^ " %%i in ('reg query HKCU\Environment ^| findstr /i /c:"a-b-c"') do set a-b-c=%%i

        for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=-" %%a in ('echo/%%a-b-c%%') do (

            set A=%%a
            set B=%%b
            set C=%%c
            echo/%A% %B% %C%
        )
```

---

**:: Quando não for mais necessário usar a chave, você remove a entrada ::**

```bat
reg delete HKCU\Environment /v a-b-c /f 2>nul >nul
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode salvar variáveis em arquivos com a extensão `.bat`.

Para salvar o valor das variáveis num arquivo com o nome `VAR.bat` é necessário limpar as informações dele caso existam com o comando:

```
ECHO. > VAR.bat
```

Depois:

```
ECHO SET A=%A% >> VAR.bat
ECHO SET B=%B% >> VAR.bat
ECHO SET C=%C% >> VAR.bat
```

Para recuperar o valor da variável basta utilizar o comando `CALL` para chamar o arquivo `VAR.bat` que já está com o comando `SET` que irá redefinir as variáveis com o valor que foi salvo no arquivo:

```
CALL VAR.bat
```

> No início da programação você irá chamar o arquivo e no final salvar ele.